# Can I sync user properties to AD both ways?

Tags: user-profile, my-site

I was under the impression that the UPS could be two way.  That is, I could make the 'name' field editable and if a user updates it, that change gets written back to AD, and if the name is changed in AD, that gets synced back to their profile.

However form the user profile properties page it seems that you can only export or import, not both.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. You cannot do a two way sync, only one or the other. This is a designed limitation.

See Spence Harbars confirmation of this [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/941995a8-f8ba-4c63-a382-ce8886e7015a/).

Curious note: when you work with User Profile property mappings programmatically, you **can** actually set both import and export properties, but it is not possible using UI, and definately **not** supported (and I am not sure how it would work out anyway)